# Recursive table

Tags: mysql, recursion

I'm trying to create a table with a recursive column, but It doesn't work. Later I tried it and it did work, but the I dropped the table because of a problem and now I don't know what I did.
The table's name is "security" and this is the script:

```
create table security (
id_emplo int(6) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
id_boss varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
TIP int(5) NOT NULL,
security_division varchar(40),
PRIMARY KEY (id_emplo),
FOREIGN KEY (id_emplo) REFERENCES employees (id_emple) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (id_boss) REFERENCES security (id_emple) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I have another table called "employees". If I try to create the table with only "id_emplo" REFERENCES employess... It doesn't have any problem.

Comment: sorry, it was an error because I changed the names when I wrote it, but in I wrote it well in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be very careful about types and declarations.  The following should work:

```
create table security (
    id_emplo int(6) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    id_boss int(6) ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL,
    TIP int(5) NOT NULL,
    security_division varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_emplo),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_emplo) REFERENCES employees (id_emple) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_boss) REFERENCES security (id_emplo) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b09c7) is the SQL Fiddle.

You had two main problems:

1. You had the name of the column incorrect.  It should be `id_emplo` rather than `id_emple` (although I give foreign key columns the same name as the column they refer to when I can).
2. The types were incompatible.

Comment: Yess... that's it. It didn't work because of the types. I wrote it well in mysql, but I had an error with the name of the column (id_emple)=(id_emplo) because of I wrote it here instead of paste it. Thank you so much.